# Mesh is subtracting in CURA

Tags: mesh, stl

When converting to stl and slicing in CURA, the 2 meshes are subtracting. Why? Normally they merge.
I put the file here: https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:5398348
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normals on the model are mixed up, you can clearly see there's a problem when you import the model in cura and it shows top faces as red for no reason,
open the model in blender in edit mode select everything and go to mesh -> normals -> recalculate outside (or inside)
You can fix normals on cura too with "mesh tools" if wanted